# VueJS blank page with webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js, vue-component, webpack-2

I am trying VueJS 2.0 with webpack and typescript. The example is pretty basic, but it always returns a blank page. There is no error in the console.

The original project is in Django but I extract out the relevant part. Here are the relevant files,

`webpack.config.js`

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        pageIndex: './frontend/index.ts',
        pageVisit: './frontend/visit.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    esModule: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src/,
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            filename: "commons.js",
            name: "commons"
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
        },
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    }
};
```

`index.ts`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

// mount
new Vue({
  render: h => h(MyComponent),
  components: {MyComponent}
}).$mount("#app");


@Component({
  template: '<button @click="onClick">Click!</button>'
})

export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  message: string = 'In visit!'
  onClick (): void {
    window.alert(this.message)
  }
}
```

`HTML` page

```
    <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="{% static 'frontend/js/commons.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'frontend/js/pageIndex.bundle.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Never mind, I solved it. I have to separate the Component into its own file in `index.ts`

Comment: It works outside of Django, but it returns blank page inside Django :|

Comment: I get the same issue. I have not been able to solve it. What did you do to correct this?

Comment: I don't quite remember my solution. Should have posted it here.